# Segmentation Fault: 11 C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am making a simple command-line Candy Crush game. This is my code below. I'm writing it in xCode then running it in Terminal using pico. The gameboard prints out correctly, but it doesn't put Xs on the board. Instead the board is printed and then a segmentation fault occurs.

```
//
// Assignment 3
//

#include <stdio.h>`enter code here`

//function headers
void displayOriginal (int img[10][10], int col, int row);

void removeOriginal (int img[10][10], int col, int row);

int main(){
  //declare variables and array
  int col = 0;
  int row = 0;
  int img[10][10];

  //call functions
  displayOriginal (img, col,row);    
  removeOriginal (img, col, row);        
  displayOriginal (img,col,row);

  return 0;
}

    //function for displaying gameboard
void displayOriginal (int img[10][10], int col, int row){   
  for(row = 0; row < 10; row++){//to create rows 0-9
    for(col = 0; col < 10; col++){//to create columns 0-9
      scanf("%d", &img[row][col]);
    }
  }
  printf("  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");//adds labels to x axis

  for(row = 0; row < 10; row++){
    printf("%d", row);//add labels to y axis

    for(col = 0; col < 10; col++){                  
      if (img[row][col] == 1){ //red
        printf("\x1b[41m  ");
      } else if (img[row][col] == 2){//green
        printf("\x1b[42m  ");
      } else if (img[row][col] == 3){//purple
        printf("\x1b[43m  ");
      } else if (img[row][col] == 4){//blue
        printf("\x1b[44m  ");
      } else if (img[row][col] == 5){//magenta
        printf("\x1b[45m  ");
      } else if (img[row][col] == 0){
        printf("XX");
      }
      printf("\x1b[m"); //white
    }
    printf("\n");            
  }
}

//function to label where the X's go
void removeOriginal (int img[10][10], int col, int row){
  //variables
  int previous = -10;
  int temp;
  int tally = 1;

  for(row = 0; row < 10; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < 10; col++){
      if (previous == img[row][col]){//if previous block =current then add 1
        tally++;
      } else {
        tally = 1;//return to 1 if previous does not equal current
      }

      if (tally >= 3){
        previous = img[row][col];
        for (temp = (tally-1); temp >= 0; temp--){
          img [row-temp][col] = 0;
        }
      } else {
        previous = img [row][col];
      }
      printf("Row %d Col %d Tally %d", row, col, tally);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What a unique title ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this before posting questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should use a debugger to run your program to get where occurs the segmentation fault (and other usefull information like variable values)

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that row >= temp in this section? If it isn't, img[-1][col] will result in a segmentation fault.

```
if (tally >= 3)
            {
                previous = img[row][col];
                for (temp = (tally-1); temp >= 0; temp--)
                {
                    img [row-temp][col] = 0;
                }
            }
```

Comment: >I chaged the code and i still got the seg fault. This is what i changed it to:   if (tally >= 3)
            {
                previous = img[-1][col];
                for (temp = (tally-1); temp >= 0; temp--)
                {
                    img [row-temp][col] = 0;
                }
            }

Comment: Why? Your array is of size 10. So img[1], img[2]... img [9] will work. Anything outside this range will result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: I meant img[0],img[1]... img[9]

Comment: While out-of-bounds array access is certainly always undefined behavior in C, going over by a small amount *generally* won't cause a segmentation fault if you remain within a mapped page.